# Discord bot does not start

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm creating my first discord bot while following their guide. When launching the bot with: `node index.js`. This returns: "ReferenceError: FinalizationRegistry is not defined". Has anyone else encountered this problem while following their guide. Here's the code from the guide.
index.js

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(token);
```

config.json

```
{
    "token": "my token is here"
}
```

Comment: Never seen that error. Can you show the trace stack?

Comment: Are you on Node.js version 16?

Comment: @LoganDevine Thank you for pointing that out. I was on 14.x.x from when I was at work earlier. I shall close the thread now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be on version 16.x for Discord.js >=v13.